# Treat '^M' as regular characters in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file that contains text to generate LaTeX mathematical expressions, one per line. This file should contain exactly 103,559 lines. But some lines contain the character sequence '^M' (CTRL-v CTRL-m) either at the end or interspersed within the lines, possibly multiple times. As a result, when I try to read the lines from the file using Python, the number of lines returned is greater than expected (actually returns 104,654 lines).

How do I tell Python to not generate a newline on each occurrence of the sequence '^M'? Thank you.

Comment: Can't you replace/remove the characters beforehand? E.g., on *nix, with `sed`?

Comment: What is the end-of-line characters sequence in this file? Is it `'\n'` new-line only, or ^M then `'\n'` together, or something else? In other words, do you want to ignore all occurrences of ^M or just those that are not immediately followed by the new-line character? Also, what should be done with the ^M characters--should they be deleted, or replaced with another character, or just treated as any other character and not causing a line break?

Comment: @Rory Daulton The end-of-line character sequence should be '\n'. I want to ignore all occurrences of '^M' anywhere in the text file.

Comment: @9769953 I've never used `sed` before. I'll take a look at it. Thanks.

Comment: @9769953 Your suggestion to use `sed` worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Don't convert newline when reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202438/dont-convert-newline-when-reading-a-file)

Comment: What do you mean by "ignore all occurrences of '^M'"? Remove the character or leave it in without starting a new line or something else? Part of your problem is the vagueness in your problem specification.

Comment: @RoryDaulton Apologies for being vague. I wanted to remove the characters outright.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `newline` argument to `open()`.

Nearly a duplicate of [Don't convert newline when reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14202438/dont-convert-newline-when-reading-a-file), from where I got this solution:

```
with open(sys.argv[1], 'r', newline='\n') as fh:
    for i, line in enumerate(fh):
        print(i, line)
```

(Be aware that, when printing as in this example, the `^M` (`'\r'`) character will put the current point at the start of a line, overwriting existing characters.)